Mongo transaction in NestJs between services
I have 2 services, each has its own transaction block like this:
function tranA() {
    const session = await this.connection.startSession();
    try {
        session.startTransaction();

        // Query with the session

        await session.commitTransaction();
    } catch {
        await session.abortTransaction();
    } finally {
        await session.endSession();
    }
}

In one controller, I have to call these 2 services, and make sure that they use
the same transaction i.e. same session. How should I approach this?
My only idea so far is to move the queries into separate functions, then pass
the session down, like this:
function tranA() {
    const session = await this.connection.startSession();
    try {
        session.startTransaction();

        this.A(session)

        await session.commitTransaction();
    } ...
}

function A(session) {
    // Query with the session
}

then in the controller, I create my own session then call the services.
The biggest problem with this approach is the duplication of method names. Now
many methods will have 2 versions, one with external session, one with its own
session.

Can you make session an optional parameter, and conditionally create it within the service?
I am not quite familiar with Nest, it seems it has an option for custom decorators, but in vanila node, the transaction decorator can be implemented like this:
async function inTransaction(f, session=null) {
    let result;
    if (!session) {
        const newSession = await this.connection.startSession();
        try {
            newSession.startTransaction();
            result = await f(newSession);
            await newSession.commitTransaction();
        } catch (error) {
            console.log("An error occurred during the transaction:" + error);
            await newSession.abortTransaction();
        } finally {
            await newSession.endSession();      
        }
    } else {
        result = await f(session);
    }
return result;


async function A(arg1, arg2, sessionFromUpstream=null) {
    return inTransaction( session => {
        // body of the function A, for the sake of demo:
        return arg1 + arg2;
    }, sessionFromUpstream);
}

This way the inTransaction decorator will create a session, start the transaction, execute the body of the function, complete the transaction and close the session. If the session is passed from upstream, e.g. the controller, transaction management should be handled there, and the function A will just use the existing session.
